# Adding column to pyspark dataframe based on conditions from other pyspark dataframes

Tags: pyspark, user-defined-functions

I am currently learning pyspark and currently working on adding columns to pyspark dataframes using multiple conditions.

I have tried working with UDFs but getting some errors like:

```
TypeError: 'object' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

from pyspark.sql.functions import udf, struct
from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType, StringType, FloatType
from pyspark.sql.functions import pandas_udf, PandasUDFType
#first dataframe (superset)    
df1 = simple_example1
#second dataframe
df = diff_cols.dropna()

def func(x,y):
    z = df1[(df1['a'] == x) & (df1['b'] <= (y+10000000000)) & (df1['b'] >= (y-10000000000))]
    z = z[(z["c"] ==1) | (z["d"] ==1)]
    z = z[(z["e"]!=0) | (z["f"]!=0) | (z["g"]!=0) | (z["h"]!=0)]
    return 1 if z.count() > 3 else 0
udf_func = udf(func, IntegerType())
df = df.withColumn('status', udf_func(df['a'],df['b']))
```

what i am trying is as follow:
1. for each row of df filter data from df1 where parameter a is equal to the parameter in df and parameter b should be in between b-10 to b+10
2. then filter that data further with either c or d = 1
3. then filter that data further if any of parameters from e f g h are non 0
4. then count number of rows in the subset and assign 0/1
5. return this 0/1 in status column of df

Comment: Can you upload input/output table example it's hard to understand from the description. Even break the example to steps

Comment: Eitherway this is not the way to use UDF, you are not manipulating or accessing Dataframes inside the udf.

Comment: Thanks for the input, I will try to think of other ways to solve it, Please give some recommendations if possible

Comment: is it possible to do like this:
def func(x,y,a1):
    z = a1[(a1['a'] == x) & (a1['b'] <= (y+10000000000)) & (a1['b'] >= (y-10000000000))]
    z = z[(z["c"] ==1) | (z["d"] ==1)]
    z = z[(z["e"]!=0) | (z["f"]!=0) | (z["g"]!=0) | (z["h"]!=0)]
    return 1 if z.count() > 3 else 0
udf_func = udf(func, IntegerType())
df = df.withColumn('status', udf_func(df['a'],df['b'],df1))